# Delete the files on the destination which are found in the source using rsync

Tags: rsync, deleted-files

I was wondering is there any way to delete all the files in the destination using `rsync` which are found in source. I have 30+ dir in source and 100+ files on the destination

I want only the 30+ in the destination to be delete recursively wondering if `rsync` or any other would help me do that...

Source

```
a/
b/
c/
```

destination

```
a/
abc/
xyz/
b/
c/
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that `rsync` can do that, but you can make a list of files, modify that list and copy it as a script to the destination.

Assuming that your file names don't contain newlines or single quotes (`'`), run this on the source machine:

```
cd basedir
find . -type f | sed 's/^/rm -f '\''/' | sed 's/$/'\''/' > /var/tmp/to_remove
```

then copy over the `to_remove` file to the destination machine, `cd` to the base directory there and source it. Any files not in existence, but that are in the list will not have any effect, and others only available in the destination will not be touched.

If you also want to delete directories you can use an additional, but this  deletes directories that exists in the source and are empty in the destination, regardless of whether there were files removed from the directory or not.

```
find . -depth -type d | sed 's/^/rmdir -f '\''/' | sed 's/$/'\''/' > /var/tmp/to_remove
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd a
find . -type f -print0 | ssh ${server_name} "cd $path_to_b;cat | xargs -0 rm"
ssh ${server_name} "find ${path_to_b} -empty -type d -delete"
```

You will get error messages for the files in a that doesn't exist on b. The second command deletes empty folders on the destination.